# How do you parse a named parameter into a route in Sinatra?

Tags: html, sinatra

I am creating a bookmark manager application that gives a list of links. Each link has one or more tags. I want to give the website user the ability to filter links by tag. The user should be able to type the name of the tag and then click a button labeled 'Filter by tag'. This should provide a list only of links that have that tag.

Thus, my html form is as follows:

```
<form action='/tags/:name’ method='get'>
  <label for='name'>
    Tag:
    <input type='text' name='name'>
  </label>
  <input type='submit' value='Filter by tag'>
</form>
```

My controller is as follows:

```
class BookmarkManager < Sinatra::Base
  get '/tags/:name’ do
    tag = Tag.first(name: params[:name])
    @links = tag ? tag.links : []
    erb :'links/index'
  end
end
```

I ran rackup, and tried to filter my links using a tag. When I typed and submitted the name of a tag, the name submitted was ‘:name’ rather than the typed text. As a result, instead of displaying the links related to a particular tag, no links were displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a magic route /:name, I suggest you pass name as a queryString parameter.  Your app should work just fine if you change the HTML to be this:

```
<form action='/tags' method='get'>
  <label for='name'>
    Tag:
    <input type='text' name='name'>
  </label>
  <input type='submit' value='Filter by tag'>
</form>
```

And change the sinatra route to be this:

```
class BookmarkManager < Sinatra::Base
  get '/tags’ do
    raise ArgumentError, "Name is required in order to show a tag" unless params[:name]
    tag = Tag.first(name: params[:name])
    @links = tag ? tag.links : []
    erb :'links/index'
  end
end
```

Also, the route now throws an exception if name is not passed to the route.  This is a good way to validate your inputs.

Comment: Thanks Harper that does work, but I was trying to make my controller more RESTful. Thus, I would like my route to relate to a particular tag, when I am filtering my links by that tag.

Comment: If you want to make your app follow the RESTful standard, then your backend should return JSON or XML which is parsed by the recipient on the front end then rendered into the view.  See https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Would you mind accepting my answer, since I solved the question as you asked it (nothing was mentioned about REST)?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem as follows:

In html:

```
<form action='/tags' method='get'>
  <label for='name'>
    Tag:
    <input type='text' name='name'>
  </label>
  <input type='submit' value='Filter by tag'>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
class BookmarkManager < Sinatra::Base
  get '/tags' do
    redirect "/tags/#{params[:name]}"
  end
  get '/tags/:name' do
    tag = Tag.first(name: params[:name])
    @links = tag ? tag.links : []
    erb :'links/index'
  end
end
```

So now when I filter by tag, my URL will display the tag name.